# WordPress Customizer - pass setting value into another control to live update drop-down choices

Tags: taxonomy, theme-customizer

In the WordPress customizer script, I am trying to pass the value from a select control into a custom control that displays taxonomies associated with the selected value (1st control).

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new Tax_Dropdown_Control( $wp_customize, 'select_tax', array(
    'section'       => 'section_1',
    'label'         => __( 'Select Post Taxonomy', 'textdomain' ),
    'description'   => __( 'Select a taxonomy based on post type selected.', 'textdomain' ),
    'dropdown_args' => array(
        'post_type' => $wp_customize->get_setting("select_post_type"), // here I need to pass the first setting's value
    ),
) ) );

// custom controls related snippet
class Tax_Dropdown_Control extends WP_Customize_Control {
    .....    
    $dropdown_args = wp_parse_args( $this->dropdown_args, array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
    ) );
        
    $dropdown_args['echo'] = false;
                
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($dropdown_args);
                
    if  ($taxonomies) {
        echo '<select>';
        foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
            echo '<option>'. $taxonomy. '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    } 
    ....
}
```

It would need to update the choices live when the select post type is changed. I'm not sure if maybe an `active_callback` can be used to recall the function with the updated variable?

Comment: How do you add the `select_post_type` control? What's the code? And those `echo` (`$taxonomies`), what control/section are they in/for?

Comment: @SallyCJ the `select_post_type` is a select control. The $taxonomies is the code for the `select_tax` custom control class in the render content function

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use some JavaScript to capture the selected option and then make an Ajax call to the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/) to fetch the corresponding posts and update the second field.

Answer (score 0):

The customizer does everything client side, so retrieving a new taxonomy list would involve an ajax call to the rest api. That's doable, but pretty complicated. An easier, but uglier solution would be to simply include all dropdowns and toggle their display. So you would have this inside a loop through all thinkable dropdowns:

```
foreach [ thinkable dropdown ] {
....
if  ($taxonomies) {
    echo '<select id="' . $taxonomies . '">';
    foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
        echo '<option>'. $taxonomy. '</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
    } 
}
```

This will lead to `html` like this:

```
<select id="tax1">
 <option>...</option>
 <option>...</option>
</select>
...
<select id="tax5">
 <option>...</option>
 <option>...</option>
</select>
```

Next, you can use the `id` on `select` to apply css to toggle the display. Obviously you don't want this ugly `html` on your live site, so you'll have to use [`is_customize_preview`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_customize_preview/) to make sure this is only generated when the customizer is active.